# Как показать offline html страницу другим людям?

Tags: html, css, ссылка, offline

Как показать простой дизайн сайта без скриптов(только html, css) другим людям? важно учитывать что я не хочу скидывать файлы, можно ли как то через ссылку?

Comment: Можно: отправляешь этим другим людям приглашение со ссылкой на свое местоположение (т.е., с физическим адресом), и когда они к тебе приходят - показываешь.

Comment: Выкладываете сайт на хостинг (как вариант - можно бесплатно хостить статический сайт на [github pages](https://pages.github.com)), скидываете ссылку другим людям.

Comment: Лучше запусти сайт у ся на локалке и продемонстируй клиенту  через TeamViewer

Answer (score 2):

Тут важно понимать: если Вы не хотите отправлять людям файл html + css, потому что опасаетесь воровства с их стороны, то единственный способ показать им результат работы - сделать скришот страницы и выслать картинку.

В любом другом случае (если Вы выложите сайт на хостинг и отправите им ссылку), они смогут легко скопировать html и css из браузера. По сути это будет то же самое, что и отправка файлов по почте.